# Jenkins (How to check if job exists, without script permissions)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would to check if a certain job exists in jenkins.
That is all there is to it, as I"m in a shared jenkins so I cannot ask for script permissions.
Is there a way to check without requiring extra permissions?

P.S I don't want to trigger it, just check if it's there

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the Jenkins APIs. You can use an Xpath expression with the API to filter out the exact information you need.

```
http://JENKINS_URL/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&xpath=/hudson/job/name/text()[contains(.,'JOBNAME')]&wrapper=job_names&pretty=true
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot do that, because I cannot hardcode my credentials to query the Jenkins and I don't have a shared jenkins user

Comment: @WhoAmI In that case I don't think there is another way.